# Multiple JPA queries error

Tags: jsf, maven, jpa, named-query

I want to run multiple queries using `@NamedQueries` annotation but it is giving error that :

```
1. The attribute value is undefined for the annotation typed NamedQueries
2.NamedQueries can not be resolved to a type
```

Following is the code:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="findAllBookItems",
            query = "SELECT i FROM Book i where i.isbn > 1 "),
    @NamedQuery(name="findAllCDItems",
    query = "SELECT c FROM CD c where c.numberofcds >=0 ")
})
```

Do i need to define this annotation somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe an import statement?

```
import javax.persistence.*;
```

Plus of course you need the JPA implementation among your libraries.

Comment: Vote the answer up, then.  Thanks!

Comment: Normally if you're using Eclipse, you can solve this problem "automatcaly" using Ctrl+Shift+O. Regards,